# How can I export to image a Chart with react-chartjs-2 and add logo or whatever stuff in image?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, react-chartjs-2

I need to export to image a Chart with react-chartjs-2 and add logo or whatever stuff in image.

I'm doing this

```
    const exportImage = useCallback(() => {
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = `Chart${today}.png`;
        link.href = refChart.current.toBase64Image();
        link.click();
      }, [refChart]);
```

But don't works!
error: toBase64Image is not a function
My component is a Div
but that Div have logos and chart

Please you help!
Thanks

Comment: maybe try [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.